# Should off-topic questions be downvoted?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I often see interesting but off-topic questions. Should they still be downvoted, or is flagging as off-topic and leaving a comment enough?

Comment: Sorry for the obvious duplicate, I did search before asking but didn't see it :/

Comment: Once in a while you'll even stumble upon questions that deserve an upvote for research, presentation or even interestingness, but still don't fit the format / need to be voted off-topic.

Comment: I think this is a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what version of off topic they are. If the question is well researched but simply doesn't fit the exchange it was posted on, then the close vote/flag may be enough.

However, if the question has not been researched, is a commonly asked poor question, or is clearly disregarding of easy to recognize standards then I think a downvote is appropriate as it helps to discourage other users from repeating the same type of post.